# search input on JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, search, input

how to make an input like on the google site? I need that after entering the texts and in the input, Google opens with the desired request.

on JAVASCRIPT

google's input
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnNkB.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPhiQ.png)

my input(html)
`<input class="finder" type="search" placeholder="Search in Google">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an event listener to let's say a button.
When that button is clicked, the value in your search field will be added to the end of a Google search link.

However, since you can expect people to type sentences (and urls don't use spaces), you can use `replace()` to replace all spaces with, in our case, a `+` (url format for spaces is `%20`, but spaces in queries are commonly replaced with a `+` character).

Lastly, you can use `window.open()`, to open a new window that uses our link.

UPDATE: You can use a keypress as a trigger for the eventlistener, and then check if the entered key is an "Enter", that way you don't need a button.

Here's an example:

- SEARCH_GOOGLE_VALUE is the textfield the user can type

```js
const SEARCH_GOOGLE_VALUE = document.getElementById('SEARCH_GOOGLE_VALUE');

SEARCH_GOOGLE_VALUE.addEventListener("keypress", (keyboard) => {
if (keyboard.key == "Enter") {
    let value = SEARCH_GOOGLE_VALUE.value;
    value = value.replace(' ', '+');
    
    let link = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + value;
    window.open(link);
}
});
```

Comment: I need to do it without a button. And by pressing ENTER.

Comment: You can use "keypress" instead of "click", that way everytime you enter a key in the input field, the function will be called, then you can just set an if -statement to proceed only if the entered key is "Enter"; I'll change the code.

Comment: Thanks for changing the code but I have a problem. error "SEARCH_GOOGLE_VALUE is null " . I don't understand why. I added "id="SEARCH_GOOGLE_VALUE" to the input. Or do I need to add something else?

Comment: This means that JS can't find your element on the page. Make sure the ID tags are the same in both your HTML and your JS.
It might also be that you place your JS before your HTML-elements, then the JS can't find the element as it doesn't exist yet, make sure to place your JS below your HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean redirect to a google page after input this would work

```
document.querySelector('.finder').addEventListener('focusout',function(){
location.replace("https://www.google.com/search?q=" +     document.querySelector('.finder').textContent);
});
```

this will send the user to a google page with the needed requests when they leave the input fild

if you need to make something simular but on your oun website the best option would be to send the user to a nother page with the query data in the url and some back end to construct and return a needed page.

or you could send a fetch and get info back on focus out

Comment: I don't understand how focusout works? What should I do? Reset focus by clicking on an empty space?

Comment: if you click out side the input this triggers a focus out if you whant some thing on input this would work for you https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_trigger_button_enter.asp